# Validation inside logical statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following logical test inside my T-SQL database's update script:

```
IF ((COL_LENGTH('dbo.Trackers','DeviceId') IS NOT NULL) AND (COL_LENGTH('dbo.Devices','UserId') IS NOT NULL))
   UPDATE [dbo].[Devices]
   SET [UserId] = (SELECT TOP 1 t.UserId FROM Trackers t WHERE t.DeviceId = [dbo].[Devices].DeviceId);
GO
```

...which gives me this error:

> Invalid column name 'DeviceId'.

OK, the column Trackers.DeviceId really don't exists anymore, but the first part of my statement is supposed to block this validation, or am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because the query is compiled and during this process the server check for syntax. It send you this error since the colum does not exist it cannot be mapped during this process.

Comment: I think you are right. Maybe I'll need to run an 'sp_executesql' inside my IF.